# is there an iphone (Cydia) app to forward/back 30s

Tags: iphone, applications, jailbreak, ios

With **SBSettings+Activator** one is able to program the physical buttons on the iPhone, to open apps, toggle settings, skip to next/previous song, play/pause musik, open controls, etc.

Is there something like this to program a physical button to (when listening to a podcast or audiobook) skip forward/back 30s (within the same track)?